# Lavarel & Vue e-commerce: how to post an order as array of products instead of single product

Tags: laravel, vue.js, local-storage, e-commerce

I am kinda new to both Laravel and Vue and I am working on a school project. I have been following a guide and trying to develop the product but I have the following problem: in the guide was only possible to do an order with a single product. Using LocalStorage a created a Cart component where you can add several products instead. How do I use axios.post to correctly post the order in the database now?

app/Http/Controllers/OrderController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Order;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class OrderController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return response()->json(Order::with(['product'])->get(),200);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $order = Order::create([
            'product_id' => $request->product_id,
            'user_id' => Auth::id(),
            'quantity' => $request->quantity,
            'address' => $request->address
        ]);

        return response()->json([
            'status' => (bool) $order,
            'data'   => $order,
            'message' => $order ? 'Order Created!' : 'Error Creating Order'
        ]);
    }

    public function show(Order $order)
    {
        return response()->json($order,200);
    }
```

Resources/JS/views/Checkout.vue (between < script > tag):

```
     placeOrder(e) {
                e.preventDefault()

                let address = this.address
                let product_id = this.product.id
                let quantity = this.quantity

                axios.post('api/orders/', {address, quantity, product_id})
                     .then(response => this.$router.push('/confirmation'))
            },
```

App/Http/Models/Order.php

```
<?php
    namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

    class Order extends Model
    {
        use SoftDeletes;

        protected $fillable = [
            'product_id', 'user_id', 'quantity', 'address' 
        ];

        public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
        }

        public function product()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id');
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, You can achieve your goal by changing many lines of code instead of using your current code at backend (laravel Model-Controller) and frontend (Vue). I will show you how to do by adding hasMany relationship in your User model structure, then changing saving method at controller, and axios request payload. This method has limitation, you have to post an array of products of the same user ID.

1. Add hasMany relationship in your User Model. Read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

```
class User extends Model
{
    //add this line
    public function order()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
```

2. Use `createMany` function to save multiple rows in your controller. Read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method)

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //use this lines to store array of orders
        $user = Auth::user();
        $orderStored = $user->order()->createMany($request->data);

        //return your response after this line
    }
```

3. Change your axios payload from vue method

```
data(){
    return {
        //add new key data to store array of order
        arrayOfOrders:[];
   };
},
methods:{
    placeOrder(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        let address = this.address
        let product_id = this.product.id
        let quantity = this.quantity
        //remark these lines, change with storing to arrayOfOrders data instead of doing post request
        //axios.post('api/orders/', {address, quantity, product_id})
                //.then(response => this.$router.push('/confirmation'))

        this.arrayOfOrders.push({
            product_id:product_id,
            quantity:quantity, 
            address:address
        });
    },
    //create new function to make post request and call it from your button
    postData(){
        let instance = this;
        axios.post('api/orders/', {
            data:instance.arrayOfOrders
        }).then(response => this.$router.push('/confirmation'))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer! Just one thing is not so clear.. in my OrderController.php should the final code look something like this?

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $order = $user->order()->createMany([
            'product_id' => $request->product_id,
            'user_id' => Auth::id(),
            'quantity' => $request->quantity,
            'address' => $request->address
        ]);

        return response()->json([
            'status' => (bool) $order,``
            'data'   => $order,
            'message' => $order ? 'Order Created!' : 'Error Creating Order'
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: you don't need to arrange array of data again when using createMany function manually, because the array of data has been set from frontend. But if you really want to set it again, you need to pass multidimensional array insted of single array. Please read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method)